# MySQL Returning Unique combinations from many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my first post so please be kind.

I am trying to get to grips with SQL, using MySQL, I am having trouble returning unique results from queries where there are more than 2 tables. 2 tables is OK as I can use a not equals in the where clause to create unique vales.

Can someone explain the concept of how to do this for 3 or more tables.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
Table1     Table2     Table3

Number     Number     Number
1           1          1
2           2          2
3           3          3
4           4          4
```

When I run my query I will get 1,2,3 and 1,3,2. All I need is one of the possible results.

With 4 numbers there are a total of 24 combinations from the 3 tables. However I only want the unique combinations which is 4 combinations i.e.[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,3].

The SQL that I have is

```
SELECT Table1.Number,Table2.Number, Table3.Number 
    FROM  Table1,Table1 AS Table2,Table3
    WHERE
        Table1.Number <> Table2.Number and  Table1.Number <> Table3.Number 
    GROUP BY Table1.Number , Table2.Number , Table3.Number
    HAVING Table1.Number <> Table2.Number
        AND Table1.Number <> Table3.Number
        AND Table2.Number <> Table3.Number;
```

What I am trying to do is de-duplicate all variances of the 3 numbers chosen.

Comment: If you want results in a particular order, using `order by`.

Comment: `select * from Table1 order by Number` will return: 1, 2, 3. But that's for a single table. Now, why do you want to combine all three tables?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but if you just want to join the tables and be sure that you don't get permutations of the same values, you can use `<` instead of `!=`. Then you'll get just one result of 1, 2, 3, not also 1, 3, 2 and 2, 1, 3 and... when you use it as `table1.column < table2.column and table2.column < table3.column`

Comment: I have updated my post to show each table with 4 numbers. With 4 numbers there are a total of 24 combinations from the 3 tables.  However I only want the unique combinations which is 4 combinations i.e.[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,3]. I hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with unique combinations. Unique in what sense? Also, please rewrite your question such that it includes (i) an input table with, say 5 rows, (ii) an expected output table, and (iii) the corresponding SQL statements (DDL and DML). Thank you!

Comment: @EntropyUK how is combination [2,3,3] uniue but [2,2,3] or [1,1,1] not unique

Comment: how and there be only 24 combination. there would be 4*4*4 combination = 64

Comment: @RajivShah No. You've just calculated the total number of combinations where [1,2,3] and [1,3,2] will be counted. I think they want the ["Number of combinations with repetition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) which incidentally is calculated for us on that page and it's 20, not 24, see "Example of counting multisubsets"

Comment: @EntropyUK Please define your meaning of "unique combinations". I don't understand how there can be 24. Especially since you've listed [2,3,3] as being part of your desired result. Is [1,1,1], [1,2,2], [2,4,4] or [2,3,4] also part of your desired result? Also please include your query that you say works for only 2 tables.